# Need help w/ existing cast-iron, wet-vented single to double vanity conversion

Tags: plumbing

I'm removing a single vanity and my master bath & replacing it w/ a double vanity. Once I removed the drywall, I discovered that the vanity is currently wet vented, which is something I'm not very familiar w/ as a DIY, non-plumber. Hoping someone here can give me some advice about how to deal w/ this.

My general thought is to remove the horizontal cast-iron pipe, in favor of PVC (is that allowed?). Then from there maybe add a wye for the first drain keeping it all horizontal, and the last w/ just a simple 90 like what's on there now. Thanks for the help in advance!

[image]  [image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMXsD.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wet venting for this arrangement is not that complicated.

The important thing for you, a non-plumber [I'm educated in the ways of plumbing, but not a plumber either], to remember is that your *horizontal* pipe, **isn't.** It's **sloped** 1/4" per foot (2%) towards the drain/vent stack. The Vent is the air on top of the fluid in the pipe.

As a 2" pipe, your traps can be located up to 8 feet from the stack, so you are well within that restriction, and you should also be fine from the number of DFUs connected since it's just a pair of lavatories (sinks, not kitchen, utility, or mop types.) The 8 foot for 2" pipe restriction keeps the pipe from being filled to the point that you lose the vent air on top of the fluid, since the pipe rises 2" over that 8 feet (or an inch over your actual 4 feet, and perhaps another 1/4" if it comes out a foot or so before the trap bend.)

Cut off your cast iron pipe with enough length left that you can move the **hubless connector** you already have to transition to PVC (or get a new one if it seems at all dubious from age.)

Comment: Yup, that's what I was thinking as well.  This is all great information, thanks so much!  If you're still around, I had a few more questions; Given that my cast iron pipe is 4" & it's not inset into the wall on the left, the PVC l likely can't start until about 16-20" away from the wall.  That means it'll be past my far left sinks drain.  Is it reasonable to just angle the P trap toward the center?  Also, why not just join the two P Traps into a single PVC outside the wall?